# Dental clinic database design - teeth problem

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm struggling with the designing part for my college project of a dental clinic database. I'll have a table for the doctors, one for the patients, one for the possible treatments with their price list and now the appointments part.

So basically you should be able to appoint a given patient to a given doctor(s) for a given treatment on a given tooth or teeth. You can treat one tooth or a few teeth. You can apply many treatments to one tooth as well. And you should be able to make easy and effective SQL queries about those teeth afterwards.

So as far as I've thought about it, I could leave writing down teeth numbers to doctors and make a column for the teeth in the appointment table. But the doctors can make a mistake then. Or I can make a new table for just teeth with only one column like tooth_id but that doesn't sound like the best solution to me.

The numbering of teeth:

11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,

21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,

31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38,

41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48.

What would you do?
I'm working in MySQL, just mentioning.

Comment: *I could leave writing down teeth numbers to doctors and make a column for the teeth in the appointment table. But the doctors can make a mistake then.* Make clickable picture similar to sеandard tooth scheme/layout, not numeric inputbox.

Comment: Yeah that would be some kind of a solution but we're supposed to do everything in pure *SQL

Comment: In MySQL you may use ENUM (if you need one tooth per table row) or SET (if a set of teeth from one till all 32 per row is possible).

Comment: What is the question? Do to accomplish what given what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table for patient, table for doctor, table for teeth, and table for threatment.
Then, the one doctor can have many clients (1:N), or even (N:M), its your decision if a patient can have other doctors. Patient 1:N with teeth; and teeth with threatment well, i dont know how this works.

But yes, I would make a table with only the tooth id, and the foreign key of the threatments.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it doctor-centric: table doctor will contain availability of said doctor, so DOCTOR_PK will have a time range of the appointment, the doctor_id, and patient_id (of course it could be null and a FK if present).

Patient could act as a connection table between two domain tables in a many to many relation: TREATMENT_TYPE and TEETH.

At this point a doctor will know that during a given time frame will have a patient who is in need of this and that.

PS: it's a generic structure, it coould become much more complex with more specific requirements